# pull info from all files that include "feedback" (from several different directories)?

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach, find

I've been searching to find a way to pull out a matching line from certain files in several different directories. 
--The phrase I'm searching for: "position director"
--The file name it's found in: "feedback_tac*" (each feedback_tac has a different numerical ending, hence the "*")
--The "feedback_tac" files are found in directories structured like this:

~  /May/05012017/emcee/log1234/current/feedback_tac

~  /May/05022017/emcee/log2345/current/feedback_tac

~  /May/05032017/emcee/log3456/current/feedback_tac

~  /May/05042017/emcee/log45767/current/feedback_tac

~  /May/05052017/emcee/log873565/current/feedback_tac

~  /May/05062017/emcee/log9610/current/feedback_tac

if I use: find . -name "feedback_tac*" I get a listing of all the files I need, but I'm having trouble putting them through the foreach loop, or creating an array. I've done some foreach loops before, but this one is giving me fits for some reason.

(Unix AIX, and perl v5.6.1):

Comment: find ./ -name "feedback_tac*" | xargs grep "position director"

Comment: Wow, I was making that waaaay harder than it needed to be... That was perfect and succinct, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./ -name "feedback_tac*" | xargs grep "position director"
```